# Questions and Confusion about Manifest "Requirements" Section

Tags: excel, manifest, office-addins, excel-web-addins, office-store

my company has provided older, VSTO-style add-ins to access our data for years. We've recently created a 100% new add-in using the web-based, Excel Javascript API and we're looking to have this distributed via the Office add-in store.

We're publishing the add-in iternally via the O365 Admin process, making it an "admin managed" add-in, and this is working fine but obviously will not for public distribution. Use of this add-in requires a subsription to our company's products, however this is not managed within the add-in. Users are directled to Auth0 for authentication and can use the credentials they use to access our other web-pased data products.

That said, we've run the manifest through the validation process. However, I have run into a couple of issues. I filled in the "requirements" section of the manifest with the feature versions we're using. We're mainly targeting user of the most recent versions of Excel for Windows and Macs, as the add-in dpeends on new features. However, there are discrepencies in the the  section.

This is what we're

```
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.17" />  -->
      <Set Name="RibbonApi" MinVersion="1.2" />  
      <Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.2" /> 
      <Set Name="OpenBrowserWindowApi" MinVersion="1.1" />
      <Set Name="DialogOrigin" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
```

However, the validator claims there is not ANY Office product that supports "DialogOrigin" requirement set.However, I find it clearly documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/common/dialog-origin-requirement-sets?view=powerpoint-js-preview

That said, upon further reading, I am not using cross-domain messaging between dialogs and parents, so I don't think I need this one ... BUT I am curious as to why the "npm run validate" script doesn't recognize it?

My second issue, is that even if I remove DialogOrigin, when I submit the manifest via the O365 Admin page, it's rejected with the same error - there are NO Office products that support what I am saying is required. This is DESPITE of the fact that the validator says it's OK. More so, if I have ANY requirements in there at all aside from "SharedRuntime" - O365 rejects it.

This section is not important for our iinternal uses as we're all using the same verison of Office, and have control over this. But, for external clients, we obviously want this to be accuate, and also for the store submission process as it's my understanding that the testing / validation will be based on these requirements.

What am I missing with this manifest section?

I have tried every combination of this section in the Manifest, and I still do not understand what a proper configuration looks like. I don't want to submit to the Store until I can at least have a manifest in our O365 that has the REQUIREMENTS section included.

EDIT:

To add some clarity, my Requirements section is located here:

```
      <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Workbook" />
      </Hosts>
      <Requirements>
        <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
          <Set Name="SharedRuntime" MinVersion="1.1" />
          <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.17" />
          <Set Name="RibbonApi" MinVersion="1.2" />  
          <Set Name="DialogApi" MinVersion="1.2" /> 
          <Set Name="OpenBrowserWindowApi" MinVersion="1.1" />
          <Set Name="CustomFunctionsRuntime" MinVersion="1.3" />
        </Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <DefaultSettings>
```

My specific questions are:

1. Is this the correct location? Do any of these settings belong in the VersionOverides section? That section only has "AllFormFactors" and "DesktopFormFactor" configured, if that makes any difference.
2. Does anyone know why, when I upload for internal users to our O365 "Admins" console, the manifest is rejected (No office products support the requirements) if the Requirements are anything BUT SharedRuntime?
3. The "npm run validate" command accepts the requirements provided it does not contain DialogOrigin, which is in the docs but doesn't seem to be supported anywhere. Any idea why this is even a different result from the O365 Admin console?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem with a Word add-in, and I found the following disclaimer buried in [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)

> Important
>
> The DialogApi 1.2 requirement set can't be specified in the  section of an add-in manifest. You will have to check for support for DialogApi 1.2 at runtime using the isSetSupported method as described in Runtime checks for method and requirement set support. Support for manifest requirements is under development.

The runtime method is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#runtime-checks-for-method-and-requirement-set-support)

Comment: Oh, good find ... that certainly answers that question, thanks! I have already added runtime checking for all the requirement sets since I posted the question. I still have the outstanding issue that when I upload to O365 for an Admin deployment (for internal users) if I put ANY requirement sets in the manifest aside from SharedRuntime O365 rejects the submission, stating there are no Office products that meet the requirements. This is obviously not true given the runtime check for all of them pass. For store submission, I believe this section determines testing scope.